# Switch case final в PHP или почему goto это плохо

Tags: php, архитектура, инспекция-кода

### Проблема

Есть задача при использовании `switch` у разных `case` выполнять еще и код из `default` (или например `final` реализовать), что бы не дублировать одинаковый код в разных кейсах.

```
switch ("b") {
    case 'a':
    case 'z':
    case 'q':
        echo "a\n"; // not need run default action
        break;
    case 'b':
        echo "b\n"; // need run default case without case 'c'
        break;
    case 'c':
        echo "c\n";
    default:
        echo "default"; // need run for "b" & "c" cases
}
```

Выводит:

```
b
```

А хотелось бы:

```
b
default
```

Если убрать `break` у варианта `b`, то будет выполнен лишний код

```
b
c
default
```

Есть решение через `goto`, что является плохим стилем кодирования:

```
switch ("b") {
    case 'a':
        echo "a\n";
        break;
    case 'b':
        echo "b\n";
        goto caseFinal;
        break;
    case 'c':
        echo "c\n";
        goto caseFinal;
        break;
    default:
        caseFinal:
        echo "default";
}
```

### Полная задача

Есть массив полей разных сущностей и нужно разные действия у разных полей сделать.

```
switch ($fieldName) {
    case 'id': // не нужно default
        unset($properties['actions']['create']);
        unset($properties['actions']['edit']);
        break;
    case 'content':
        // одинаковый код нужно вынести в defaut
        unset($properties['actions']['dashboard']);
        // ...
        break;
    case 'isDeleted':
        // одинаковый код нужно вынести в defaut
        unset($properties['actions']['dashboard']);
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        // код нужне для всех остальных полей + кейсы выше
        unset($properties['actions']['dashboard']);
}
```

### Вопрос

Как это сделать без использования `goto`? Может есть вариант с другим подходом в архитектуре.

P.S. Если `goto` здесь уместен ([лично я не боюсь динозавров](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.goto.php)), то почему это плохой стиль кодирования?

Comment: тело default вынесите из case и будет вам счастье. `goto` не плохой, просто им мало кто умеет пользоваться, поэтому лучше забыть про него.

Comment: @BOPOH тогда для кейса "а" будет выполнен лишний код

Comment: ну тогда `if не равно a: выполнить ваш код` ). И че-то мне кажется, что такой код будет куда более читабельным, чем с goto

Comment: @BOPOH а если будет много таких кейсов, то придется частично дублировать работу `switch` через `if`, а хочется избавиться от дублирования ключей и дублирования кода

Comment: вы может не ту задачу решаете? Делаете ваши а, бэ и прочее классами и там уже реализуете такое поведение. Ну может и не классами их делать, а просто вынести обработку этих значений в отдельные классы. Если у вас будет куча таких значений то как-то не совсем удобно с этим работать будет и без всяких там goto

Comment: @BOPOH добавил описание полной задачи, просто классами это не исправить, как мне кажется

Comment: сделайте свитч в свитче. но сама архитектура уже сильно напрягает.

Comment: @Etki имеете ввиду еще один `switch` в `default` первого?

Comment: ну если классами не исправить, то методами легко можно: например, есть массив callback'ов, которые вы вызываете в зависимости от вашего значения. Т.е. тело каждого case в данном случае - это какой-то метод. Только если у вас и правда такие небольшие действия выполняются, то не уверен что такой подход себя оправдает. В default много действий надо? Если всего пара, то и не страшно будет их внутри case оставить. Если что-то объемное, можно его в метод перенести и из каждого case вызывать уже этот метод

Comment: если switch всего на несколько строчек (как в примере), то любое другое решение может оказаться "из пушки по воробьям", от goto профита никакого не будет, так что и заморачиваться не стоит

Comment: @BOPOH да, такой подход самый разумный, но хочется еще проще и лаконичней, на уровне синтаксиса решить.

Comment: я имею в виду fall-through для case x: case y:, в котором выполняется некоторая логика, после которой идет свитч. но, повторюсь, это вообще не решение.

Comment: можно ввести переменную run_add_code= false, и в нужных случаях задавать ей true. Тогда будет достаточно в одном месте поправить, чтоб этот код выполнился

Comment: немного о goto http://habrahabr.ru/post/114211/

Comment: Goto ненавидят только полные нубы. Причём ненавидят демонстративно, чтобы казаться умнее. Так они считают. Но мало кто знает, что и switch тоже считается плохим стилем. Пользуйтесь всеми инструментами языка, исходя из здравого смысла, а не потому, что какой-то крикун что-то там кричит о каком-то там стиле.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

После изучения ответов, статей и умозрительных эксперементов, пришел к выводу.

### Вывод

В данном случае использование `goto` допустимо, пока не будет добавлена подобная конструкция в синтаксис `switch` и если соблюдаются условия:

1. Ты уже не `Junior`
2. Переходить можно только вперёд
3. Заходить в блоки и выходить категорически нельзя

Любой `while` и вложенные `if` так же опасны как `goto`. Для выхода из множественных циклов есть `break N`.

**Плюсы которые я вижу**

1. Краткость и простота кода при соблюдении вышеописанных условиях
2. Меньше занимаемой памяти и скорее всего быстрота выполнения
3. Лучше "плохой тон", чем много избыточного кода, который сложнее поддерживать

Для себя я решил использовать только в группах исключающих условий:

```
switch ("b") {
    case 'a':
        echo "a\n";
        break;
    case 'b':
        echo "b\n";
        goto caseFinal;
        break;
    case 'c':
        echo "c\n";
        goto caseFinal;
        break;
    default:
        caseFinal:
        echo "default";
}
```

Конечно при усложнении логики и увеличении строк кода, лучше всего воспользоваться ответом [n4nn31355](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/189022/n4nn31355) и выносить в классы и отдельные методы, но внутри у них все равно наверно будет что-то похожее ;)

Интересные статьи на эту тему:

1. [Запретный плод GOTO сладок](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114211/)
2. [GOTO or not GOTO вот в чём вопрос](http://habrahabr.ru/post/271131/)

Comment: Что за бред? Вам дали нормальный ответ, а вы накидали какой-то треш и еще пометили как правильный...

Comment: @Artur возможно вы просто не в состоянии воспринять этот код, равно как и писать аккуратные комментарии

Comment: @Artur и хотелось бы аргументы, а не просто "треш"

Comment: По комментарию, скажите что подкорректировать чтобы он был более аккуратным. По коду - действительно не могу воспринять. Мы тут на ревью избавляемся от лишнего if/else в пользу состояний, стратегий и полиморфизма для того чтобы сделать код более очевидным и читаемым, а вы предлагаете вернуться к методам, которые и 15 лет назад считались гавнокодом. Хорошо хоть, что в конце написали примечание про усложнение и увеличение строк кода.

Answer (score 9):

Зачем усложнять? Можно вынести повторяющийся код в функцию/метод класса и вызывать их из каждого кейса.
Кода получится ровно столько же, зато `goto` мы не используем и код остаётся читаемый и легко поддерживаемый:

```
function someAction() {
    //some code
}

switch ($fieldName) {
    case 'id':
        unset($properties['actions']['create']);
        unset($properties['actions']['edit']);
        break;
    case 'content':
        someAction();
        unset($properties['actions']['dashboard']);
        // ...
        break;
    case 'isDeleted':
        someAction();
        unset($properties['actions']['dashboard']);
        // ...
        break;
    default:
        someAction();
        unset($properties['actions']['dashboard']);
}
```

Comment: Да, но хотелось всю обработку собрать в одном методе и не использовать декомпозицию. Может потребоваться много параметров передавать (по ссылкам в том числе), или сразу доп. классы реализовывать и кол-во кода увеличится соответственно

Comment: Кстати я именно так чаще всего поступаю, и со временем очень много методов образуется маленьких

Comment: ООП и стайл гайды ООПшных языков обычно и предполагают небольшие легко читабельные методы. Не вижу тут проблемы

Comment: Проблема в том, что придётся тогда для этого отдельный класс делать для обработки полей, а много классов усложняет чтение программы, согласитесь, проще линейный листинг в 50 строк прочесть чем 10 с кучей вхождений

Comment: Класс один раз написал в отдельном файле, нормально методы назвал, структурировал, отладил и забыл про реализацию и эти 50 строк в процедурном стиле не маячат постоянно перед глазами.

Comment: Частично согласен, но выносить в отдельный класс, если нет повторного использования я считаю излишним. Если кол-во кода вырастит и логика добавится, то конечно. Но мне сам вопрос стал интересен про свитч кейс

Answer (score 1):

Если только одно действие не должно быть продолжено `default`, почему бы не попробовать вынести `default` действие за `switch` и огородить `if ($fieldName != 'id') { unset($properties['actions']['dashboard']); }`

Comment: да, но если таких кейсов будет много, то придется много "городить" и + дублирование названия полей

Comment: Всё, что делает default, завернуть в функцию. В нужных кейсах добавляется всего-то один вызов функции.

Comment: @banme да, вариант, но не хотелось быть сильно декомпозицию и так не сложного метода делать. Хочется всю обработку полей в одном методе сделать

Comment: goto на самом деле не всегда так плох, как говорят. В `switch` можно сделать `goto default`?

Comment: @Sergey нет, в switch default зарезервированное слово. Можно только свою метку

Answer (score 0):

Можно оформить условия как отдельные функции (методы).

Ключевая функция. Получает действие на входе и выполняет соответствующую функцию:

```
function make($action) {
    if ($action()) 
        $default();
    return;
}
```

Собственно действия. Возвращают *true* или *false* как маркеры необходимости выполнять действие по умолчанию.

```
function a() {
    echo "a\n";
    return false; // дефолтное действие выполнять не нужно
}

function b() {
    echo "b\n";
    return true; // дефолтное действие выполнить нужно
}
```

Функция (метод) для действия по умолчанию:

```
function default() {
    echo 'default';
    return;
}
```

Используем:

```
make('a');
```

Comment: вариант конечно интересный, но во-первых кода стало больше, во-вторых при ООП походе кода в таком решении кода будет еще больше и в третьих усложняет чтение кода

Comment: Не думаю, что код станет менее читаемым. Здесь [каждая функция выполняет ОДНУ И ТОЛЬКО ОДНУ задачу](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Принцип_единственной_обязанности). В методологии SOLID речь идет о классах, но сути это не меняет.

Comment: Здесь каждая функция выполняет две задачи: эхнуть что-то свое и сообщить вызывающему о том, нужно ли вызывать еще что-то. Прозрачность такого кода стремится к нулю.

Comment: Хм. С тем, что выполняются две задачи - согласен.

Answer (score -2):

Усугубим `goto`

```
...
if (b == 'a') {
    echo "a\n";
    goto done;
} else if (b == 'b') {
    echo "b\n";
    goto default;
} else if (b == 'c') {
    echo "c\n";
    goto default;
}
default:
    echo "default";
done:
...
```

И кто скажет что это отвратительно - тот просто ничего не сечёт в программировании:)

Comment: `default` в `goto` не прокатит, это зарезервированное слово

Comment: @korytoff Используйте что прокатит. Что за вас всю программу и без ошибок составить? Это-то же можно додумать, правильно?